Debreu's cardinal representation theorem for finite outcome set
Suppose there are three dimensions. $x,y,z\in X^3$.
Independent: $z_ix\succsim z_iy\iff z'_ix\succsim z'_iy$.
When $X$ is connected topological space, Debreu proved that weak order, independent, and continuity imply the existence of a separable utility: $U(x)=u_1(x_1)+u_2(x_2)+u_3(x_3)$.
Now, suppose that $X$ is just a finite set: $X=\{1,2,...,n\}$.
Is it possible to also have the Debreu's representation?

Debreu also required three essential factors.
